# Google Developer Tools for javascript modification doesn't work for long 'js' file

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I am trying to edit a website, whose UI lacks the property what I want. I can navigate over items using KeyUp or KeyDown (keyboard keys). However, when it scrolls the window, it performs unnecessary animation and I want to remove this feature.
I used Google Developer Tools to browse and edit the main javascript file, but it doesn't change the webpage's features even if I edit the code. I think it's because the script file is written in one line so that it can't be properly displayed in 'not pretty' (or normal) mode of Source tab, where I can edit the code. The reason that I am suspecting this is that the code shows until it's end in pretty mode, but in not pretty mode, the source code is cut somewhere before the end of the file.

Is there anyway to get over this problem? The website I want to modify is as follows:
https://www.gqueues.com/main

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the javascript it wont execute unless it is called, so you are probably binding to keyboard events but the code never gets executed because it does when the js loads, and not when it is edited.

I would suggest adding the functionality you want using the console if you can't edit the file on the server.